# Elasticsearch cluster setup

Tags: elasticsearch, structure

I'm curerntly running a single node ES-Instance. As there are some limitations with a single server setup in ES, and the queries are becoming pretty slow sometimes, I want to upgrade to a full cluster.

The ES-Instance currently only stores data, and is **not** doing any fancy stuff (Transformations, Ingest Pipelines, ...). All I currently need is a place to store my data at, and to retrieve it (Search + Aggregations). There are more reads than writes.

In a lot of forums and blog posts I read about the "Split-Brain" issue. To circumvent this, the minimum node count should be 3.

The idea is to keep the amount of machines low, because this is a private project and I do not want to also manage a lot of OS in my spare time..

The structure I thought about was:

```
- 1 Coordinator + Voting-only Node
- 2 Master-eligible + Data Nodes

minimum_master_nodes: 2 to circumvent Split-Brains
```

Send all ES-Queries to the Coordinator, which will then issue the requests on the data nodes and reduce the final results.

**My question is:** Does this make sense? Or is it better to use 3 master-eligible + Data nodes?

Online I found no guidance for ES-Newbies to get an idea of the structure of a simple cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in right direction and I can see most of your thinking is also right so don't consider yourself as ES newbie :).

Anyway as you are going to have 3 nodes in your cluster, why note make all three nodes as master eligible nodes and why you are making a dedicated co-ordinating node when by default every ES node works as a co-ordinating node and in your small project you won't need a dedicated co-ordinating node. this way you will have a simple configuration, just don't assign any explicit role to any node as by default all ES nodes are master, data and co-ordinating node.

**Also, you should invest some time to identify the slow logs and its cause to make it more performant rather than adding more resources that too in personal project**, please refer to my [short tips on improving the search performance](https://opster.com/blogs/improve-elasticsearch-search-performance/)